# I can't add a separate image to each article

Tags: python, django

**I can't add a separate image to each article**

```
            {% for article in articles %}
            <li>
              <a href="{% url 'postDetail' id=article.id %}"><img src="{% static 'article.image.url' %}" alt="img" />
              </a>
              <div class="title"><a href="{% url 'postDetail' id=article.id %}">
                  <h2>{{article.title | safe}}</h2>
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: what happens, any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing it incorrectly. You do not need to specify static again.Try this.

Replace this `<img src="{% static 'article.image.url' %}" alt="img" />`

with

```
<img src="{{ article.image.url }}" alt="img" />
```

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: {% for article in articles %}
79                 <li>
80                   <a href="{% url 'postDetail' id=article.id %}"><img src="{% article.image.url %}" alt="img" />
81                   </a>
82                   <div class="title"><a href="{% url 'postDetail' id=article.id %}">
83                       <h2>{{article.title | safe}}</h2>
84                     </a>
85                   </div>
86                 </li>
87                 {% endfor %}

Comment: The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.   ERROR

Comment: Have you uploaded the Image file using an `ImageField` ? If yes then it will work. Unless you set `DEBUG=False` in which case you need to configure static_file server.